# How would you model this curved vase?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

See pictures for said vase. The marble vase is meant to hold two bottles. It's almost like an infinity sign. It's two cylinders, but connected smoothly. I tried mirroring the cylinder but got stuck when I had to connect them. Would I use a curve? Please explain with detail because I am a beginner. Thank you.

3/4 view[image: 3/4 view]top view[image: top view]side view[image: side view]x-ray view[image: x-ray view]

Comment: I wish more questions were asked that well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[image]e

1. Make a 6 Sided Circle, use the mirror modifier and extrude a side to form a
   bowtie"
2. Apply the Mirror modifier and delete the edges/ faces made in the middle
3. Select both vertices in the middle and press 'S' to scale them uniformly
   towards the center to form a slope.
4. Add in a Subdivision modifier to  smooth everything.
5. Select the whole thing Press 'F' to fill then Select the filled face
   and press 'I' to inset to the desired thickness.
6. Extrude to get the desired height.
   hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: I love that it's based on hexagons!

Answer (score 6):

Create a mesh circle, go in edit mode:

[image]

Select half of it, press <kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>:

[image]

Now select these 4 guys here

[image]

and subdivide uneven times:

[image]

Turn on proportional editing, select these 2 guys in the middle

[image]

and move with <kbd>S</kbd> and moving your mouse, use scroll wheel to change your influence radius:

[image]

[image]

Now in edit mode select all, press <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude and <kbd>Z</kbd> to fix to z-axis, move down. Then add solidify modifier and use autosmooth.

Answer (score 4):

Create a circle, in *Edit* mode cut a part, duplicate and rotate 180°, fill the gap between the 2 circles:

[image]

Subdivide once the long edges, select the new vertices and scale down:

[image]

Bevel these 2 new vertices with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yay, and here is the Geometry Nodes version! ;-)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a bezier or other curve to get the 8 looking shape, then convert it to a mesh and extrude the edge to the height you want. Then use a solidify modifier to get the thickness you want. You can then apply modifiers and further edit the mesh to your liking, like filling in caps if there are any, adding loops and a subdiv mod, etc.

Be sure to add enough resolution to the curve before converting it to a mesh. You can subdivide the curve with the right click context menu.

Comment: How would I make sure the bezier curve has a perfect circle if I can only adjust the segments by eye-balling it?

Comment: @WolfHasQuack There's a Bezier Circle object for that.